# Regex Extract Google Data Studio: Need to slice one field delimited with pipes into separate fields

Tags: regex, looker-studio, regexp-substr, re2, xregexp

I have a field in which values look like:

| Field |
| --- |
| pos1-123|pos2 xyx123|pos3-abc|pos4x350 |

I want to slice the field into four different calculated fields using REGEXP_EXTRACT that look like:

- Calculated Field 1 : `pos1-123`,
- Calculated Field 2 : `pos2 xyx123`
- Calculated Field 3 : `pos3-abc`
- Calculated Field 4 : `pos4x350`

I've managed to pull Calculated Field 1 on my own by using:

```
> REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field, '^//|(//|[[:alnum:]]+)')
```

However, I'm getting stuck on iterating through the rest of the string.

Comment: Maybe `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL` with `([^|]+)` will do?

Comment: I think because Google Data Studio uses RE2 the REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL function isn't allowed.

Comment: Ok, use 1) `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field, '^([^|]+)')`, 2) `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field, '^[^|]+\|([^|]+)')`, 3) `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field, '^(?:[^|]+\|){2}([^|]+)')` and 4) `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field, '^(?:[^|]+\|){3}([^|]+)')`

Comment: This is working perfectly now thanks! My only change is that in RE you need two \'s to escape a token so:  ^(?:[^|]+\\|){2}([^|]+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regular expressions:

```sql
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field, '^([^|]+)')
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field, '^[^|]+\\|([^|]+)')
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field, '^(?:[^|]+\\|){2}([^|]+)')
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field, '^(?:[^|]+\\|){3}([^|]+)')
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^|]+\\|){3}` - three occurrences (`{3}`) of

  - `[^|]+` - any one or more chars other than `|`
  - `\|` - a `|` char
- `([^|]+)` - Capturing group 1: any one or more chars other than `|`.